# iPhone SDK - Play Audio/Video through UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwebview, media

I want to know if I could play a mp3 file or mp4 (video) file through an UIWebView by loading a simple url request. I have already tried sending the UIWebView to a video link (e.g. http://google.com/blah.mp4) but it will flash a quick QuickTime logo and show a black screen. However in MobileSafari it streams fine. Is there anyway to play a media file through an UIWebView??!

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag.

Linda